# How check values in a SPA webform

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, single-page-application

I want to make a Web Single Page Application (SPA). I think i will choose angular or backbone. In both case, i am wondering something: Users will fill forms in the application. I will include some checks (email format, required fields, numbers, etc.)
In the past, i was working with pure PHP. In this time, i used to do those checks on server side, because users can send malicious data, by bypassing the webworm.
I see on some tutorials that checks are made in javascript, in the client browser. So i do not know what to do...

Comment: Always double check, front side and server side.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your checks on server side anyway: angularjs is based on a RESTful architecture, so you should either checks on the server for malicious attacks and in the client to prevent them (a double check).

Javascript **is** readable and modificable by client: you should take this in consideration and **always** don't trust your users when they send you inputs.

So, do some soft checks in javascript (like input not filled, wrong types ecc.ecc.) but always check for their correctness on server side.